# Java and SWT: Threads and Listeners

Tags: java, swt, listener

I'm actually new to Java and SWT, so my question might sound dumb.
I've looked over the intrnet (and stackoverflow) but all the answers and examples are too complex for a noob like me.

I have a class, call it Admin. When I click a button, it launches a method in another class(Handler).

1. In Admin I have a progress bar, that should increase with the
   operation in Handler.
2. I don't know how much time the operations in
   Handler takes, but I know I have 9 of them.
3. I would like, somehow,
   to inform Admin when each method has finished.

What I have so far: (non relevant parts omitted)

Admin.java:

```
ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(this, SWT.SMOOTH);
Button btn = new Button(this, SWT.NONE);
btn.setText("Update");
btn.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener() {
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                btn.setEnabled(false);
                thread.start();
            }
        });
Handler handler = new Handler();
final Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
                handler.run();
                for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
                    final int value = i;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(800);
                    } catch (Exception e) { }
                    display.asyncExec(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                            bar.setSelection(value);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
```

Handler.java:

```
public class Handler implements Runnable{

void m1() {...}
void m2() {...}
...
void m9() {...}

public void run()
{
 m1();
 m2();
 ...
 m9();

}
```

With this implementation, the call to handler.run() works fine, and the progress bar is filling, but of course they are not "corelated" in any way.

I will appreciate your wisdom!
Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by correlated? Do you mean synchronized?

Comment: He means that after m1() finishes the progressbar isn't 1/9 on its way.

Answer (score 1):

The highly coupled way of solving this, is to have the `Handler` take a `ProgressBar` as input in the constructor, and after `m1()` finishes, it updates the progress to 1/9 and so on. A better (more decoupled) way to do it, is that you can "listen" to `Handler`, and that `Handler` fires an event with its progress after each method finishes. Then you can update in the `Admin.java`.

Comment: ^ this! How "listeners" and firing an event can be merged to my files? Also, is there a way for Handler to no implement Runnable? (Isn't the thread in Admin enough for that?).

Comment: Hmmmm... anyone? Can someone please provide a link to a tutorial or something similar for this matter?

Comment: The Internet is flooded with tutorials on usage of Listeners, and Java/Oracle provides the best.  Just search for "tutorial actionlistener".

Answer (score 1):

I will ask you to consider using [`ProgressMonitorDialog`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fdialogs%2FProgressMonitorDialog.html) from JFace if adding this library to your application is not much of a problem. Your code then would look something like below:

```java
ProgressMonitorDialog dialog = new ProgressMonitorDialog(parent);
dialog.run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {
    @Override
    public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
            InterruptedException {

        monitor.beginTask("my work", 9);

        m1();
        monitor.worked(1);

        m2();
        monitor.worked(1);

        ...

        m9();
        monitor.done;
    }
});
```

You can also send the `monitor` instance into your `m*` methods for even detailed reporting. Have a look at [`SubProgressMonitor`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fcore%2Fruntime%2FSubProgressMonitor.html) for dividing each *one* of your initial 9 ticks further before sending them into each `m*` method.

But this means that your progress bar is a new dialog which might not be acceptable to you so in that case the first answer suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks Waqas Ilyas, but Jface is not allowed, only SWT. Thanks everyone, I'll try to find a simple tutorial.